# My code throws an IndexError: list index out of range

Tags: python, python-3.x, face-recognition, face-detection

The following code is throwing indexError list index out of range
I tried googling it and everybody is talking about range() errors and calling an index that does not exist. I followed the following tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sz25xxF_AVE&ab_channel=Murtaza%27sWorkshop-RoboticsandAI letter for letter and still got the error
starting to feel like it is a problem from my python or something. My python version is 3.7

the code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import face_recognition
import os
import pickle

path = 'known_faces'
images = []
classNames = []
myList = os.listdir(path)
print(myList)

for cl in myList:
    curImg = cv2.imread(f'{path}/{cl}')
    images.append(curImg)
    classNames.append(os.path.splitext(cl)[0])
print(classNames)

def findEncodings(images):
    encodeList = []
    for img in images:
        img = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
        encode = face_recognition.face_encodings(img)
        encodeList.append(encode)
    return encodeList

encodeListKnown = findEncodings(images)
print('encode complete')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    success, img = cap.read()
    imgS = cv2.resize(img,(0,0),None,0.25,0.25)
    imgS = cv2.cvtColor(imgS, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

    facesCurFrame = face_recognition.face_locations(imgS)
    encodeCurFrame = face_recognition.face_encodings(imgS,facesCurFrame)

    for encodeFace,faceLoc in zip(encodeCurFrame, facesCurFrame):
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
        faceDis = face_recognition.face_distance(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
        print(faceDis)
        matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)

        if matches[matchIndex]:
            name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
            print(name)
```

I known that I am not putting `[0]` at the end of some lines, but that also throws the same error, and now I've reached a dead end

Comment: In what line does the error occur? You are indexing `classNames` using `matchIndex` which you calculate before. This is most likely the source of the error.

Comment: With Python, always include the error and backtrace (formatted as code). That makes things much clear: people can immediately see where the error occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this error said that -> in a loop -> you try to access an item, which does not exist - cause it's out of range.

```
if matches[matchIndex]:
```

or

```
name = classNames[matchIndex].upper()
```

in this case, match is a list, and the index is the position of an element in the list.

---

if 1 case is wrong then:

```
matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(encodeListKnown,encodeFace)
matchIndex = np.argmin(faceDis)
```

values of matches are higher than match index (cause of the error)

analogic to the 2nd case.